# Command ran as wrong user on boot while explicitly being told to run as root

Tags: users, startup, daemon

So I've installed Syncthing and I'm running in a lot of problems getting this program to run as root on boot. For some reason it always runs as the default user ( thom ), but I boot into root and tell it to run as root. The command looks like this:

```
sudo start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --chuid root  --exec /usr/bin/syncthing -- "--no-browser"
```

And is placed inside rc.local. Running rc.local manually AFTER booting works fine, the booting itself is not working. This is the only program thus far that's consistently running as the wrong user. Perhaps someone can help point out what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `$HOME` defined in `/etc/rc.local` so when `syncthing` resolves its configuration location `$HOME/.config/syncthing` it's finding `/.config/syncthing`. I suspect that this contains details for your local user, thom, whereas when `$HOME=root`, `/root/.config/syncthing` contains details for root.

Also, you don't need `sudo` when you're already root (as in `/etc/rc.local`).

Try this instead:

```
HOME=/root start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --exec /usr/bin/syncthing -- "--no-browser"
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't do anything now. As if the command is ignored.

Comment: @Nos have you tried removing `--quiet` to see what it's doing?

Comment: I removed --quiet and made it output any errors to a logfile like this.
HOME=/root start-stop-daemon --start --background --exec /usr/bin/syncthing -- "--no-browser" > /root/Desktop/log
But the logfile is empty.

Comment: @Nos that can't capture errors. Remove your redirect and watch during the boot process.

Comment: I can't really watch the boot process as the NAS is on a remote location.

Comment: To add, I can do it, but it's a bit of a pain to do so. If there's another way to debug it I'd prefer that.

Comment: @Nos ok let's start from a different direction. Is there a `/.config/syncthing` and/or `/root/.config/syncthing`? If so, is root's configuration correct?

Comment: /.config does not exist. /root/.config/synycthing does exist and has one config file, config.xml. This config contains the correct settings. Perhaps I should add the paths point to a HDD using ZFS with ZFSOnLinux. Not sure if this is relevant.